# php and mongo db find doc by name and text legnth

Tags: php, arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query

hi i need help with php and mongo db .
i have docs in my server like this:

```
comment: "aaaaaa"
id: "11111"
_id: {$id: "564c5a297efcf0181d00002c"}
active: true
flag: 7
```

i need to give it a sting of ids

```
$ids = "5555,3333,2222,11111"
```

and i need to search in my docs for all the result with this ids
i do it like this:

```
$query = array("id" => array('$in'=> $where));
```

its working ok but now i need to add anoter condition.

i need to find all the ids in my docs but the one that have also

```
"active" => true,
"comment.length" > 2
```

so the rusult query wil give me all the docs that has one of the ids && active = true && comment.length > 2
i manage to find a solution for the active and comment.length with this:

```
    $jsCond = "function() {
    return this.comment.length > 2 && this.active == true ;
    }";
```

but and dont have any idea how to make it work good.

i need help!! thanks!

Comment: Did you check http://php.net/manual/en/mongodb-driver-manager.executequery.php ?

Answer (score 0):

i have solved it:

```
$jsCond = "function() {  return this.comment.length > 2 && this.active == true ; }";

$query2 = array( '$and' => array(
    array("id" => array('$in'=> $where)),
    array('$where' => $jsCond )
));
```